# How to find home screen icon size from screen resolution

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, resolution

I am building a prank mobile application that simulate the mobile home screen.

When the user start the application it looks similar to the actual home screen.

I am going to do this by laying down images of icons in a grid. These images would be common icons that found in mobile phone screen eg: mail, camera, photos etc.

I already know the width and height of the screen. But I have to resize the icon images to a size same as the actual home screen icons .

The question I have is , is there a way to figure icon sizes from the screen resolution?

Comment: You probably mean Home Screen. There is no desktop on iOS

Comment: My mistake. Yes Home Screen.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an info about the *screen resolution*, and your app is an iOS mobile app; and you want to know **the size of home screen icons** based on this information.

In the documentation by Apple on *Human Interface Guidelines*, the section on *App Icon* says that for iPhone, **icons sizes are the following**:

> 180px x 180px (60pt x 60pt @3x)

> 120px × 120px (60pt × 60pt @2x)

This answers your question.

To find out more, you may visit [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/)

Comment: #Asol thank you for your answer. It seems there are 2 sizes for iPhone. How do I identify which size goes to which resolution?

Comment: The way I am gong to do this is to draw all on the screen. To do this I need to know exact width and heights

Comment: By two sizes, you mean **pt** (points) and **px** (pixels)?
There is only 1 size for each resolution (@). 
The coordinate system iOS uses to place content onscreen is based on measurements in **points**, which map to pixels in the display.

So there is just conversion happening: 
@1, a standard resolution, 1 point = 1 px;
@2, 1 point = 2 px;
@3, 1 point = 3 px.

Comment: I was referring to 180 and 120

Answer (score 0):

Images are sizable by 1x 2x and 3x it will adjust the users resolution you don't have to do any thing else

Comment: thank you for your answer. The way I am doing this I really need to figure out icon size based on screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know the icon sizes. You can use below code.

```
let iconImage = UIImage(named: "name_of_image")!

let heightPoints = iconImage.size.height
let heightPixel = heightPoints * iconImage.scale

let widthPoints = iconImage.size.width
let widthPixel = widthPoints * iconImage.scale
```

Comment: #Ashish Kr Singh thank you for your answer. I don't have access to the UIImage. Basically what I need is home screen icon width and height based on screen resolution.